# how to find multiple values in comma separated column?

Tags: c#

I have column called **SubjectIds** in which I saving Multiple ids by comma separated. I have to give filter on SubjectIds where I can send multiple subject id (1,5,7), and based on that data, should come..

[image: Below is example : if I send (1,4,7) then this data should come]

Comment: That's a poor design to begin with. If you do it properly and save each value separately, this issue goes away.

Comment: Are you looking for a raw SQL query or are you using EF?

Comment: Please specify more what you are looking for or the problem that occurs to you in order to help you

Comment: You have an N:M relation, so you should model it like one: Table "Tests", Table "Subjects" and Table "TestSubjects" = [TestId, SubjectId]. Then you can go wild with filters and joins ... same goes for Topics, probably.

Comment: This does not seem to be related to ASP.NET at all, but rather to database access. How do you access the database? Which DBMS?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to filter by such a SubjectId, this can be accomplished in raw SQL by using the [`STRING_SPLIT` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql):

```
select
    *
from
(
    SELECT
        value
    FROM 
    STRING_SPLIT('1,2,3,4', ',')
) source
where
    value = 3
```